DAX measure to calculate merchants with first transaction in current year
I have 3 measures to calculate active merchants in a given periods using DAX time intelligence. In addition to that, I need to also check that their first transaction (in FactTransaction) is in current relative year
Example:
For the New Active Merchants LM:
Take all the Active Merchants LM#
For these merchants, eliminate all those who do not have their first transaction/invoice in the current fiscal year (if calculated for any month in 2023 check their first transaction is in 2023, etc)
// base measure
# Merchant =
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(DimMerchant[MerchantHK]),
    FactTransaction
  )

// Last Month or Previous Month
# Active Merchants LM# = CALCULATE([# Merchant], PREVIOUSMONTH(DimDate[DateValue]))

// Last 3 months
# Active Merchants L3M# =
  CALCULATE(
    [# Merchant],
    DATESINPERIOD(DimDate[DateValue], MAX(DimDate[DateValue]), -3, MONTH)
  )

// Last 12 months
# Active Merchants LY# =
  CALCULATE(
    [# Merchant],
    DATESINPERIOD(DimDate[DateValue], MAX(DimDate[DateValue]), -12, MONTH)
  )


Table relationship:

Sample data:

DimDate (one to many to FactTransaction on DatePK)




DatePK
DateValue
Year
Month




20230901
9/1/2023
2023
9


20231001
10/1/2023
2023
10


20231101
11/1/2023
2023
11


20231201
12/1/2023
2023
12


20240101
1/1/2024
2024
1


20240201
2/1/2024
2024
2


20240301
3/1/2024
2024
3


20240401
4/1/2024
2024
4


20240501
5/1/2024
2024
5




DimMerchant (one to many to FactTransaction on MerchantHK)




MerchantHK
MerchantName




AAA
NAAA


AAA
NAAA


BBB
NBBB


DDD
NDDD


BBB
NBBB


DDD
NDDD


CCC
MCCC


DDD
MDDD


BBB
MBBB




FactTransaction (Main fact table where DimDate and DimMerchant have relationship)




DatePK
MerchantHK




20230901
AAA


20231001
AAA


20231101
BBB


20231201
DDD


20240101
BBB


20240201
DDD


20240301
CCC


20240401
DDD


20240501
BBB



